# What does "E2E use case" mean?

Tags: scrum, use-case-diagram

I know what is "use case", but I haven't any idea about "E2E" in this context.

What does "E2E use case" mean?

Comment: You mean "end to end"? Could you give some context?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 2):

It should be "End to End" Use Case.

Comment: thank you, it sounds like true))
but I don't understand difference between "End to End Use Case" and just "End to End Use Case"(

Comment: *sorry - it means just "Use Case"

Answer (score 2):

As Emil said it means End to End.

As with most terminology it can mean different things from company to company. So always ask your group to explain what they mean with this word.

For me an "End to end use-case" means *a list of steps that follow the full process from beginning to end*. For example buying some from a web-shop:

1. Open website
2. Put stuff in basket
3. Register a new account
4. Pay
5. Receive the order confirmation
6. Receive the shipping confirmation
7. Get the actual stuff

In the world of software development I would also add that it uses the full-stack (e.g. from UserInterface till database and back) as it would be in a production environment.

Other reads:

- UML E2E use-case example: http://www.modernanalyst.com/Resources/Articles/tabid/115/ID/2017/End-to-End-UML-Use-Case-Diagram.aspx

Comment: thank you so much!
I hope, that this is it))

Answer (score 0):

In my practice 'e2e' means 'End to end test scenarios' and defines business-relates scenarios.

Not checking button is checked only or control contains expected value, but describes real business processes, the value user gets moving through this process.

So this processes should be automated or checked with higher priority than others.